# How do I convert a Groovy String collection to a Java String Array?

Tags: groovy, collections

I'm trying to call a methond on a Java class from a Groovy class.  The Java method has a String array as a parameter, and I have a collection of Strings in my Groovy class.  How do I convert the Groovy collection to a Java String array?

Java Method:

```
public class SomeJavaClass{
  public void helpDoSomething(String[] stuff){

  }
}
```

Groovy code

```
class SomeGroovyClass {
  def data = ["a", "b", "c"]

  def doSomething = {
    def javaClass = new SomeJavaClass()
    javaClass(data) //Groovy passes ArrayList, Java class expects String[] ???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To be correct, `def data = ["a","b","c"]` it is a List, not an array.

Just try casting like this:

```
def data = ["a","b","c"] as String[]
```

Comment: I knew there was something groovier than 
(String[])data.toArray(new String[data.size])
Thanks!!!