# How to pass arbitrary number of arguments to Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I got this shared library  `vars/libOne` that takes `composeFileNames` parameter as a list of strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groov


def call(String param1, String param2, String parm3, String[] composeFileNames ) {

        String s =''
        for (int i = 0; i < composeFileNames.size(); i++) { s +=' -f ./'+ composeFileNames[i] }
               } 
....
```

this `libOne` is called in another shared library `/vars/libTwo` were I defined pipeline steps and Map variables I pass in Jenkins:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def call(Map pipelineParams) {
    node (...) {
      stage("call libOne"){
                libOne (pipelineParams.param1, pipelineParams.param2, pipelineParams.param3, pipelineParams.composeFileNames  )
}
```

I want to call my libTwo in jenkins  and pass two String parameters as `composeFileNames`:

```
@Library('myLib ') _
        libTwo(param1: 'string ',
               param2: 'string',
               param3: 'string',
               composeFileNames: ['string1','string2']
```

)

The question is how do I do that correctly , because the above code gives me the error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: dockerComposeVicDeploy.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) values: [param1, pamam2, param3, ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick guess, you're passing in the default Groovy construct (an ArrayList), when you want to pass in a String array (String []).  Luckily, that's easy... give this a try?

```
@Library('myLib ') _
        libTwo(param1: 'string ',
               param2: 'string',
               param3: 'string',
               composeFileNames: ['string1','string2'] as String []
```

[How do I convert a Groovy String collection to a Java String Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570659/how-do-i-convert-a-groovy-string-collection-to-a-java-string-array)